# How to get a list to populate dynamically using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, list

I have a landing page that is to display results of a naming tool/form on the page after the submit button is clicked. The results are stored in a JSON file.

I need the results from the JSON file displayed as an unordered list on the page according to the letters and categories entered in. Here are the relevant HTML and JQuery used:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#dnt').submit(function(e) {
    var cat_id = $('.dnt-overlay > select > option:selected').data('id') || 0;
    var cat_title = $('.dnt-overlay > select > option:selected').text() || 'All';
    if (cat_id === 0) {
      cat_title = 'All';
    }
    var dnt_url = $('.dnt-overlay > select > option:selected').val() || '/dog-name-finder/';
    var gender = $('.dnt-overlay > [name=gender]:checked').data('id') || 0;
    var gender_title = $('.dnt-overlay > [name=gender]:checked').val() || 'All';
    var title = cat_title;
    var html = '';

    var params = '';

    if (window.innerWidth <= 320) {
      params = '?limit=18';
    } else {
      params = '?limit=21';
    }


    if (cat_id > 0) {
      params += '&' + 'cat_id=' + cat_id;
    }

    if (gender > 0 && cat_title != 'Gender Agnostic' && cat_title != 'Unisex' && cat_title != 'Male' && cat_title != 'Female') {
      title += ' ' + gender_title;
      params += '&' + 'gender=' + gender;
      if (cat_title == 'All') {
        dnt_url += gender_title.toLowerCase() + '/';
      } else {
        dnt_url += '?gender=' + gender_title.charAt(0).toLowerCase();
      }
    }

    title += ' Dog Names';

    $('#dnt-popup > h1').text(title);
    $('#dnt-popup > .more-btn').find('a').attr('href', dnt_url);

    e.preventDefault(); // We don't need to send the form, because it's all local
    if ($('#male').is(':checked')) { // Check if male is checked
      $('#dnt-popup').removeClass('dnt-all').removeClass('dnt-female').addClass('dnt-male');
    } else if ($('#female').is(':checked')) { // Check if female is checked 
      $('#dnt-popup').removeClass('dnt-all').removeClass('dnt-male').addClass('dnt-female');
    } else if ($('#all').is(':checked')) { // Check if all is checked
      $('#dnt-popup').removeClass('dnt-female').removeClass('dnt-male').addClass('dnt-all');
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: "/dog-name-finder/json/" + params,
      })
      .done(function(data) {

        $.each(data, function(index, value) {
          html += '<li>' + value.title + '</li>';
        });

        $('#dnt-popup > .results-list > ul').html(html);

        $.magnificPopup.open({ // open pop up for male
          items: {
            src: '#dnt-popup',
            type: 'inline'

          }, //item
          mainClass: 'animated slideInRight'
        }); ///popup open


      });




  }); ///submit function 

  $('#dnt-popup > .more-btn > .long-btn > a, #dnt-popup > .more-btn > .short-btn > a').on("click", function() {

    var cat_id = $('.dnt-overlay > select > option:selected').data('id') || 0;
    var cat_title = $('.dnt-overlay > select > option:selected').text() || 'All';
    if (cat_id === 0) {
      cat_title = 'All';
    }

    var gender_title = $('.dnt-overlay > [name=gender]:checked').val() || 'All';


  }); //event for click to DNT landing page

  if ($('.dnt-landing-page').length > 0) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: "json",
        url: "/dnt.json",
      })
      .done(function(data) {

        var params = {};
        window.location.search
          .replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(str, key, value) {
            params[key.toLowerCase()] = value;
          });


        var url_base = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.hostname;

        var gender = $('input[name=gender]:checked').data('id') || '';

        var gender_title = $('input[name=gender]:checked').val() || 'All';

        var cat_id = $("div.mid-blackboard > ul > li > a.active").data('id') || '';

        var cat_title = $("div.mid-blackboard > ul > li > a.active").text();

        var url = $("div.mid-blackboard > ul > li > a.active").attr('href');

        var letter = $('input[name=letter]:checked').val() || '';

        var letter_label = letter;

        if (letter_label === '') {
          letter_label = 'no letter selected';
        }

        letter = letter.toUpperCase();

        var page = parseInt(params.p) || 1;

        var totalPages = 0;

        if (page < 1) {
          page = 1;
        }

        var pagesToShow = 5;

        var html = '';

        var match = '';
        var ltest = '';

        var refresh = false;


        $.each(data, function(index, value) {
          html += '<li class="';
          $.each(value.categories, function(index, value) {
            html += value.category_id + ' ';

          });
          html += value.title.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + ' off" style="display:none">' + value.title + '</li>';
        });

        var results = $('.dnt-landing-results > .results-list > ul');

        results.html(html);

        function updateNames(init) {

          var title = '';

          if (cat_title != 'All') {
            title = cat_title;
          }
          if (gender > 0 && cat_title != 'Male' && cat_title != 'Female' && cat_title != 'Gender Agnostic' && cat_title != 'Unisex') {
            title += ' ' + gender_title;
          }

          $('.dnt-landing-heading > h1').text(title + ' Dog Names');

          var share_url = url_base;

          match = '';

          if (cat_id > 0) {
            match += '.' + cat_id;
          }

          if (gender > 0) {
            match += '.' + gender;
          }


          ltest = match;

          if (letter !== '' && results.children(match + '.' + letter).length > 0) {
            match += '.' + letter;
            $('#' + letter.toLowerCase()).attr('disabled', false).prop('checked', true);
          }

          if (init) {
            results.children(match).slice((page - 1) * 45, page * 45).removeClass('off').css('display', '').addClass('on');
          } else {
            results.children('li.on').removeClass('on').css('display', 'none').addClass('off');
            results.children(match).slice((page - 1) * 45, page * 45).removeClass('off').fadeIn("slow").addClass('on');
          }

          totalPages = Math.ceil(results.children(match).length / 45);

          if (totalPages > 1) {
            var pager = '';
            if (page > 1) {
              pager += '<li><button>&lt;</button></li>';
            }

            var pageStart = 1;

            if (totalPages > pagesToShow && page > Math.ceil(pagesToShow / 2)) {
              pageStart = page - Math.ceil(pagesToShow / 2) + 1;

              if (pageStart > (totalPages - pagesToShow + 1)) {
                pageStart = totalPages - pagesToShow + 1;
              }
            }

            var pageEnd = pageStart + pagesToShow - 1;

            if (pageEnd > totalPages) {
              pageEnd = totalPages;
            }

            for (var i = pageStart; i <= pageEnd; i++) {
              pager += '<li';

              if (i == page) {
                pager += ' class="active" ';
              }

              pager += '><button>' + i + '</button></li>';
            }


            if (page < totalPages) {
              pager += '<li><button>&gt;</button></li>';
            }

            $('.results-pager').html(pager).show();

          } else {
            $('.results-pager').hide();
          }

          $('input[name=letter]').each(function() {
            if (results.children(ltest + '.' + $(this).val()).length > 0) {
              $(this).attr('disabled', false);
              if ($(this).val() != letter) {
                $(this).prop('checked', false);
              }
            } else {
              $(this).attr('disabled', true);
              $(this).prop('checked', false);
            }
          });


          share_url += url;
          var del = '?';

          if (gender > 0 && gender != cat_id) {
            if (cat_id > 0) {
              share_url += del + 'gender=' + gender_title.charAt(0).toLowerCase();
              del = '&';
            } else {
              share_url += gender_title.toLowerCase() + '/';
            }
          }

          if (page > 1) {
            share_url += del + 'p=' + page;
            del = '&';
          }

          if (letter !== '' && ltest != match) {
            share_url += del + 'abc=' + letter.toLowerCase();
            del = '&';
          }

          for (var k in params) {

            if (k != 'gender' && k != 'p' && k != 'abc') {
              share_url += del + k + '=' + params[k];
              del = '&';
            }
          }

          document.title = title + ' Dog Names -  Dog Name Finder';

          addthis_share = {
            url: share_url,
            title: title + ' Names -  Dog Name Finder'
          };




          if (!init) {
            history.pushState({}, document.title, share_url);
          }

        } //end updateNames

        updateNames(true);

        $('input[name=letter]').on("click", function() {

          var eventLabel = '';

          if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            letter = $(this).val() || '';
            letter_label = letter;
            eventLabel = 'clicked ' + letter;
          } else {
            eventLabel = 'unclicked ' + letter;
            letter = '';
            letter_label = 'no letter selected';
          }
          letter = letter.toUpperCase();
          page = 1;
          updateNames();


        });

        $('#reset').on("click", function() {

          $('input[name=letter]:checked').attr('checked', false);
          letter = '';
          letter_label = 'no letter selected';
          page = 1;
          updateNames();

        });

        $('input[name=gender]').on("click", function() {

          gender = $('input[name=gender]:checked').data('id') || '';
          gender_title = $('input[name=gender]:checked').val() || 'All';
          if ((cat_title == 'Male' || cat_title == 'Female' || cat_title == 'All') && cat_title != gender_title) {
            $("div.mid-blackboard > ul > li > a.active").removeClass('active');
            cat_id = $(this).data('id');
            cat_title = gender_title;
            page = 1;
            url = $(this).data('href');
            $("div.mid-blackboard > ul > li > a[data-id=" + cat_id + "]").addClass('active');
            $('#landing-submit').children('option[data-id=' + cat_id + ']').prop('selected', true);
          }
          $('.dnt-gender-dog').css('display', 'none');
          switch (gender_title) {
            case 'Male':
              $('.dnt-gender-dog.male-dog').css('display', '');
              break;
            case 'Female':
              $('.dnt-gender-dog.female-dog').css('display', '');
              break;
            default:
              $('.dnt-gender-dog.unisex-dog').css('display', '');
              break;
          }
          page = 1;
          updateNames();


        });

        $("div.mid-blackboard > ul > li > a").on("click", function(event) {

          event.preventDefault();
          $("div.mid-blackboard > ul > li > a.active").removeClass('active');
          $(this).addClass('active');
          cat_id = $(this).data('id') || 0;
          cat_title = $("div.mid-blackboard > ul > li > a.active").text();
          page = 1;
          url = $(this).attr('href');
          if (cat_title == 'Male') {
            $('#male').prop('checked', true).click();
          } else if (cat_title == 'Female') {
            $('#female').prop('checked', true).click();
          } else if (cat_title == 'All') {
            $('#all').prop('checked', true).click();
          } else {
            updateNames();
          }

          $('#landing-submit').children('option[data-id=' + cat_id + ']').prop('selected', true);


        });

        window.onpopstate = function(event) {
          window.location.href = document.location;
        };

        $('#landing-submit').change(function() {
          cat_id = $('#landing-submit').children('option:SELECTED').data('id') || 0;
          cat_title = $('#landing-submit').children('option:SELECTED').text();
          if (cat_id === 0) {
            cat_title = 'All';
          }
          url = $('#landing-submit').children('option:SELECTED').val();
          page = 1;
          if (cat_title == 'Male') {
            $('#male').prop('checked', true).click();
          } else if (cat_title == 'Female') {
            $('#female').prop('checked', true).click();
          } else if (cat_title == 'All') {
            $('#all').prop('checked', true).click();
          } else {
            updateNames();
          }
          $("div.mid-blackboard > ul > li > a.active").removeClass('active');

          $("div.mid-blackboard > ul > li > a[data-id=" + cat_id + "]").addClass('active');


        });

        $('.results-pager').on("click", "li > button", function() {
          event.preventDefault();
          switch ($(this).text()) {
            case '&lt;':
            case '<':
              page--;
              break;
            case '&gt;':
            case '>':
              page++;
              break;
            default:
              page = $(this).text();
          }
          if (page < 1) {
            page = 1;
          }
          if (page > totalPages) {
            page = totalPages;
          }
          updateNames();
        });

        $('.results-list').on("swipeleft", function() {
          page++;
          if (page > totalPages) {
            page = totalPages;
          }
          updateNames();
        });

$('.results-list').on("swiperight", function() {
          page--;
          if (page < 1) {
            page = 1;
          }
          updateNames();
        });
      });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sidebar-left-contents" class="">
  <div class="dog-blackboard"></div>
  <div class="top-blackboard"></div>
  <div class="paw-blackboard"></div>
  <div class="mid-blackboard">
    <h4>DOG NAMES</h4>
    <hr>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="" data-id="0">All</a></li>
      <li>
        <a href="" data-id="" class="active"></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom-blackboard"></div>
</div>



<form class="dnt-tool-landing" name="dnt-landing" id="dnt-landing">
  <div class="dnt-radio">
    <input type="radio" name="gender" data-id="593" data-href="" value="Male" id="male" checked><label for="male">Male</label>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" data-id="594" data-href="" value="Female" id="female" checked><label for="female">Female</label>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" data-id="0" data-href="" value="All" id="all" checked><label for="all">All</label>
  </div>
  <!-- radio buttons container  -->
  <div class="keypad-wrapper">
    <div class="keypad-buttons">
      <input type="checkbox" value="A" id="a" name="letter" checked><label for="a"></label>
    </div>
    <!-- end of keypad buttons -->
    <div class="keypad-buttons">
      <input type="checkbox" value="B" id="b" name="letter"><label for="b" class="b"></label>
    </div>
    <!-- end of keypad buttons -->
    <div class="keypad-buttons">
      <input type="checkbox" value="C" id="c" name="letter"><label for="c" class="c"></label>
    </div>
    <!-- end of keypad buttons -->
    <div class="keypad-buttons">
      <input type="checkbox" value="D" id="d" name="letter"><label for="d" class="d"></label>
    </div>
    <!-- end of keypad buttons -->
    <div class="keypad-buttons">
      <input type="checkbox" value="E" id="e" name="letter"><label for="e" class="e"></label>
    </div>
    <!-- end of keypad buttons -->
    <div class="keypad-buttons">
      <input type="checkbox" value="F" id="f" name="letter"><label for="f" class="f"></label>
    </div>
    <!-- end of keypad buttons -->
    <div class="keypad-buttons">
      <input type="checkbox" value="G" id="g" name="letter"><label for="g" class="g"></label>
    </div>
    <!-- end of keypad buttons -->
    <div class="keypad-buttons">
      <input type="checkbox" value="H" id="h" name="letter"><label for="h" class="h"></label>
    </div>
    <!-- end of keypad buttons -->
    <div class="keypad-buttons">
      <input type="checkbox" value="I" id="i" name="letter"><label for="i" class="i"></label>
    </div>
    <!-- end of keypad buttons -->
    <div class="keypad-buttons">
      <input type="checkbox" value="J" id="j" name="letter"><label for="j" class="j"></label>
    </div>
    <!-- end of keypad buttons -->
    <div class="keypad-buttons">
      <input type="checkbox" value="K" id="k" name="letter"><label for="k" class="k"></label>
    </div>
    <!-- end of keypad buttons -->
    <div class="keypad-buttons">
      <input type="checkbox" value="L" id="l" name="letter"><label for="l" class="l"></label>
    </div>
    <!-- end of keypad buttons -->
    <div class="keypad-buttons">
      <input type="checkbox" value="M" id="m" name="letter"><label for="m" class="m"></label>
    </div>
    <!-- end of keypad buttons -->
    <div class="keypad-buttons">
      <input type="checkbox" value="N" id="n" name="letter"><label for="n" class="n"></label>
    </div>
    <!-- end of keypad buttons -->
    <div class="keypad-buttons">
      <input type="checkbox" value="O" id="o" name="letter"><label for="o" class="o"></label>
    </div>
    <!-- end of keypad buttons -->
    <div class="keypad-buttons">
      <input type="checkbox" value="P" id="p" name="letter"><label for="p" class="p"></label>
    </div>
    <!-- end of keypad buttons -->
    <div class="keypad-buttons">
      <input type="checkbox" value="Q" id="q" name="letter"><label for="q" class="q"></label>
    </div>
    <!-- end of keypad buttons -->
    <div class="keypad-buttons">
      <input type="checkbox" value="R" id="r" name="letter"><label for="r" class="r"></label>
    </div>
    <!-- end of keypad buttons -->
    <div class="keypad-buttons">
      <input type="checkbox" value="S" id="s" name="letter"><label for="s" class="s"></label>
    </div>
    <!-- end of keypad buttons -->
    <div class="keypad-buttons">
      <input type="checkbox" value="T" id="t" name="letter"><label for="t" class="t"></label>
    </div>
    <!-- end of keypad buttons -->
    <div class="keypad-buttons">
      <input type="checkbox" value="U" id="u" name="letter"><label for="u" class="u"></label>
    </div>
    <!-- end of keypad buttons -->
    <div class="keypad-buttons">
      <input type="checkbox" value="V" id="v" name="letter"><label for="v" class="v"></label>
    </div>
    <!-- end of keypad buttons -->
    <div class="keypad-buttons">
      <input type="checkbox" value="W" id="w" name="letter"><label for="w" class="w"></label>
    </div>
    <!-- end of keypad buttons -->
    <div class="keypad-buttons">
      <input type="checkbox" value="X" id="x" name="letter"><label for="x" class="x"></label>
    </div>
    <!-- end of keypad buttons -->
    <div class="keypad-buttons">
      <input type="checkbox" value="Y" id="y" name="letter"><label for="y" class="y"></label>
    </div>
    <!-- end of keypad buttons -->
    <div class="keypad-buttons">
      <input type="checkbox" value="Z" id="z" name="letter"><label for="z" class="z"></label>
    </div>
    <!-- end of keypad buttons -->
  </div>
  <!-- keypad wrapper -->
  <div class="reset-button">
    <input type="button" value="Clear Letter Selection" id="reset">
  </div>
  <!-- reset button -->
  <select id="landing-submit">
                        <option value="" data-id="0">Select a Category</option>
                        <option value="" data-id="0">All</option>

                        <option value="" data-id=""> </option>
                    </select>
</form>

<div class="results-list">
  <ul>
    <li id=""></li>
    <link rel="prev" href="">
  </ul>
  <div class="dnt-results-img">
    <img src="male.png" class="dnt-gender-dog male-dog">
    <img src="female.png" class="dnt-gender-dog female-dog">
    <img src="all.png" class="dnt-gender-dog unisex-dog">
  </div>
</div>

<ul class="results-pager" style="display:none'">

</ul>
<!-- results-pager -->
</div>
```

Some of the JSON from the file:

```
[
   {
      "Name":"Aaliyah",
       "Female":594,
       "Baby":601
    },
    {
      "Name":"Abby",
      "Female":594
   },
  {
     "Name":"Abe",
      "Male":593,
     "Video Games":604
  },
  {
     "Name":"Abigail",
     "Female":594,
     "Baby":601
   },
   {
      "Name":"Abu",
       "Male":593,
      "Disney":598
   },
   {
      "Name":"Ace",
      "Male":593,
      "Fancy":600,
      "Cool":611
   }
 ]
```

Comment: Please read [mcve] - there are reams of code. Any console errors? If the AJAX works, then post a SHORT example with JS object example

Comment: so how far you got? What is not working?

Comment: @mplungjan there are no console errors. The list is not displaying at all.

Comment: Please click the `<>` and post the JS object (json in object format) and enough of the code to show the problem. We are NOT going to eyeball your code for you

Comment: @FailedUnitTest The list is not displaying at all.

Comment: Does `$('#dnt-popup > .results-list > ul')` give you the object you expect?

Comment: @mplungjan yes in the included widget. It's just not displaying on the landing page

Comment: Are any of the event handlers you use assigned to dynamic objects before they exist in the page? Then you need to delegate

Comment: Going to try that and see what happens @mplungjan

Comment: @MikeL5799 Can you setup example code on jsfiddle?

Comment: Ok will do @muasif80